# Can all site-specific badge images be shown on all profile pages?

Tags: feature-request, badges, design, profile-page, user-accounts

For example, here are top five accounts in each site (this picture was taken when I was in Biology SE).

[image: image description]

As you can see, all the badges are DNA, while Academia's badges should be hats, so on.

What do you think?

Comment: This would be neat, but it would either (1) make the per-site sprite kind of ginormous or (2) incur a ton of additional requests when viewing any profile page or (3) require badges themselves to be contained in a single kinda ginormous sprite. Not saying no, it would be really cool if it's possible, I just don't think it's an easy ask :)

Comment: @Tim sounds like a valid answer, any reason it's just a comment?

Comment: @ShadowWizard can you translate his comment to simple English? I have look up the dictionary, knowing what is *sprite* and what is *ginormous*, yet still have no idea what he says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I share [Tim Post opinion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269324/can-all-site-specific-badge-images-be-shown-on-all-profile-pages?noredirect=1#comment872692_269324) that it would be nice to have, however not so simple to achieve due to technical issues.

Each site has its own [CSS Sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) which contains most, if not all, icons used in the site e.g. vote arrows, badge icons, and more. For example, the sprites for MSE is https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/img/sprites.svg.

Now in order to include all the badge icons from all sites in each site, you will have to load all those sprites, from all sites, on each page load of the profile page, or to create one "super sprites" with all the icons from all sites. Both of these are not really feasible, hence this request will most likely be declined, or delayed until some major change is done in the way badge icons are handled.

Comment: Ok, performance is a feature. @ArtOfWarfare told something seems legit. Can you come and see?

Answer (score 1):

We're already loading all the icons for the websites, as seen on the left side of the screenshot in the question. Where are those being stored? Can't the badges be stored the same way?

Also, why do separate gold, bronze, and silver badges exist for each website? Wouldn't it be easier just define one template and then apply a filter to it on the client end to generate the proper color?

Comment: The site fav icons are more important, and used in many places, hence they got a sprites of their own. Badges are much less used, actually profile page is the only place where "cross site" badge icons might be of use, so the team didn't bother to create this "super sprites" for badges. As for color, not sure there is a cross browser way to color images, if at all.